No Bundle URL Present RN (0.75.3) metro bundler not connecting with iOS physical devices, if i build via Xcode
I have newly created a fresh react native app using
npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init AwesomeProject --version 0.75.3
I'm building the app using Xcode and trying to install it on iPad device, the build is getting successful and it installs the app on the device. But it doesn't connect with the metro bundle even after running npx react-native start
"React Native version" : 0.75.3
"react": "18.3.1"
node version : 20.17.0

it throws the below error
No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.



Make sure your app is connected with bundle server , Here some steps you can follow to debug this issue.
1.Clear Cache:
npx react-native start --reset-cache

2.Check Bundle File: If you are running a production build, ensure that the JavaScript bundle is included. You can generate the bundle manually with:
 npx react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

If you still encounter issues, let me know and any additional context about your setup!

Thank you for the reply, I have tried all these above answers, and i tried deleting pods and reinstalled the dependencies, still nothing helped

@Praveenkumar please share your email

bpk.praveensankar@gmail.com
